# Metasploit new exploits failed

Tags: exploit, metasploit

Why can't I use new exploits like exploit/multi/browser/adobe_flash_nellymoser_bof ?
I tried to access it, but I can't even find it in MSF search Adobe or Flash or anything like this.
What should I do?

Comment: I think you're using Metasploit under Kali? Which versions of Metasploit and Kali are you using?

Comment: Latest version of kali x64 bit and i think latest version of metasploit too. How can i verify version of Metasploit?

Comment: The msfconsole output already displays the version. You can manually run version command as well. Run msfupdate to pull down the latest version.

Comment: Is something wrong here? http://postimg.org/image/o2ilp4iqd/

Comment: You have a technical support issue and not an exploit issue. It is likely a problem with your install. Re-install.

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity but re-install what? metasploit?